# altering the selected value from bootstrap dropdown menu via Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started learning Javascript, so looking for vanilla Javascript answer (not JQUERY);

I have created a dynamic drop-down menu via `createDropdown` function;

The menu contains `button` elements.

Whenever a user clicks on one of these dropdown buttons,

I want an alert popup with the value, (see the `createChart` function).

I have tried variations of `dropDownMenu.selectedIndex` but it's only alerting a "undefined"
value.

```
var range = function (start, stop, step) {
    step = step || 1;
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; i < stop; i += step) {
        arr.push(Math.round((i + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100)
    }
    return arr;
};

function createDropDown() {

    var dropDown = document.querySelector('.btn[name="annual-gains"]');
    
    // <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">test</button>')

    dropDown.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        console.log("querySelectorは合ってる")
        let values = range(0.05, 1.05, .05);


        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
            let value = values[i]
            
            var myOption = document.createElement('button');
            // id
            myOption.type = 'button';
            // クラス名
            myOption.className = 'dropdown-item';
            // テキスト内容
            myOption.innerHTML = values[i];

            const dropDownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu[name="test"]');
            dropDownMenu.appendChild(myOption);
        
        }
        createChart();
        event.preventDefault();
        

    })

}


function createChart() {

    
    const dropDownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu[name="test"]');


    dropDownMenu.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        let value = dropDownMenu.selectedIndex
        alert(value)
    
    })}
        
        
createDropDown()
```

EDIT (updated with html code):

The dropdown menu was taken from bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#menu-items

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="annual-gains">
      Annual Gains
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" name="test">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Just curious, why not jQuery? You're already using Bootstrap which has a hard dependency on jQuery

Comment: [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) is for `<select>` elements with `<options>` but... 1) You haven't shown what type of element `.dropdown-menu[name="test"]` is, and 2) You are adding `<button>` elements to it, not `<option>` elements

Comment: wondering if you can use `dropDownMenu.addEventListener("change" ...` because click can be dispatching before select `changes` and not has a selected option yet.
will try to reproduce...

Comment: @phil I haven't started learning jQuery, so wanted to stick with javascript first.

Comment: @Phil I've updated the dropdown-menu html in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener to each button

```js
myOption.addEventListener("click", (event) => event.target )  //event.target is the pressed button
```

here a working example:
https://codepen.io/sarabadu/pen/YzGqgmY

Comment: Thank you.I'm looking at the codpen now. So you included the event-listener within the for-loop. Is the `dataset` portion also needed?
I am using `inner-html` to populate the values. I wonder if `dataset.values` are also need to populate the values.

Comment: Dataset is only a nice way to save data on the elements you can render as data-foo and take it as dataset.foo

Comment: Reference to dataset docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset